# Material for moisture moderation

Tags: material-science

Do you know of any material that can moderate the level of moisture of its local environment?

Example: if the desired moisture level is 30% and the local environment of the material is at 6% the material should extract moisture to achieve 30% moisture. If local environment is at 60% the material should retract.

The only material that I know of with properties similar to that, is zeolite. Do you happen to know any other of if zeolite can be used to maintain a certain level of moisture?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In small environments, silica gel can maintain limited ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are materials called [desiccants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_desiccants) which absorb water. And an open cup of liquid water can sometimes serve as a convenient source of humidity. But if you are trying to regulate the activity of water in a system to a particular level, then you may have to introduce additional phases into your system.  You'll have to design a system which gives you the activity of water you're seeking *and* satisfies the [Phase Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_rule).

It depends upon the details of the system you are trying to control (e.g. *buffer*) and it's generally not possible to arbitrarily specify all the degrees of freedom independently.

For example, you may be able control the humidity to a specific value, but not independently of temperature or pressure.